# Rad Enigma Based Upon Sketches

Tags: rebus

The answer to this puzzle is what this puzzle is missing, *besides* well drawn pictures

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> MOHAWK - HAWK + DIVERSE - DIVE + COBRA - BRA + DELIVER - LIVER
>  = **MORSE CODE**

After applying this, you now get:

> **-.-. --- -.. . ... - .- --.**   from all the lines and dots in the images themselves,
>  which is **CODES TAG**.     (Found by @Will; confirmed by OP)
>
>  (I originally followed the rebus pattern of subtracting right from left and got "TEST" out of it, but that wasn't the intended answer.)

Comment: There appears to be said code in the pictures, which looks like it says `CODES TAG`

Comment: Will's right. The pictures hide dots and dashes in them, and the answer is that the puzzle is missing a CODES TAG because I didn't want to give away that it was more than a rebus!

Answer (score 7):

Partial solution:

> The rebus is Morse Code.
>  Mohawk - hawk = mo
>  Diverse - dive = rse
>  Cobra - bra = co
>  Deliver - liver = de

The next part was tricky to figure out, but Will pointed it out in a comment.

> Using the current International Morse code, and determining which lines and dots are part of the solution:
>  The dashes and dots in the eyes of the face with the mohawk, -.-. is C.
>  The three vertical lines in the hawk's head, --- is O.
>  The vertical line and the dots representing the eyes, -.. is  D.
>  The large dot representing the pool, . is E.
>  The three dots on the cobra, ... is S.
>  The large line in the middle of the bra, - is T.
>  The wheel (dot) and base (line) of the dolly, .- is A.
>  Finally, the dashes in the equal sign and the circle representing the liver, --. is G.
>  The gives us Codes Tag, since the puzzle is missing the tag for codes.